# Getting the word before special character including whitespace or no whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string e.g.:

```
string text = "select * from value='value' and testvalue = ?test and status like ?status";
```

I have tried using regular expressions:

```
var m = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\S+)\s+="); //with whitespace
var m = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\S+)="); //without whitespace
```

I need to get my output in dynamic labels and textbox

```
output:
label             textbox
testvalue 
status
```

here in this string if already value present i dodnt want it as labels and textbox
only with question mark and like must give me output as mentioned above
if whitespaces present between '=', it must dicsard and give output

Comment: This looks like a DB Query.Do you want the result of the Query or the Query itself? It's not clear, what you want. Please be more specific and show expected result.

Comment: Would you be able to give us clear input and expected output? It's hard to understand your question as is.

Comment: @Sahana, don't try to EDIT my answer, instead click 'Add a Comment' to give a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried making a Regex that hopefully give you the result, you want:

```
(\w+)\s?(?:\=|like)\s?(\?\w+)
```

It starts by creating a `Group` matching one or more `Word` characters and an optional `white space`. Then it matches '`=`' (escaped) OR `'like'` followed by an optional `white Space` and finally creates a `Group` matching a question mark '`?`' (escaped) followed by one ore more `Word` characters.

The Regex creates `2 Groups`, which contains the Words, you are interested in.

**How to use**:

```
string text = "select * from value='value' and testvalue = ?test and status like ?status";
var m = Regex.Matches(text, @"(\w+)\s?(?:\=|like)\s?(\?\w+)");
foreach (Match match in m)
{
    label.Text += match.Groups[1].Value;
    textbox.Text += match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

**Result:**

```
label             textbox
testvalue         ?test
status            ?status
```

**Edit**:

I made a typo, it should be '`text`' in the code, not test.

**Edit2**:

You must have a Label called 'label' and a Textbox called 'textbox' to run the code directly.

Comment: Have you tried running the code, as it looks now (I had made a typo) ?

Comment: If you want to comment, please click 'Add a comment' below, don't click 'Edit'.

Comment: i tried running the code, but the regular expression give as enumeration yielded no result. i tried like this  var m = Regex.Matches(text, @"and (\w+)\s?(?:=\|like)\s?(\?\w+)");

Comment: You have misplaced an escape back slash!.Look closely at the regex, I gave you. Try 'copy and paste' the regex to avoid misplacing the escape backslash.